# How to divide up data through rows in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I need to divide data in an excel and put it into another excel using python

For Example, suppose i have an excel which has 1000 rows of data as follows

```
Name    Number

name1   number1
name2   number2
name3   number3
```

and so on

Now suppose there are 1000 rows and i need to select 200 rows at a time and put those values in another excel and then remove these 200 values from this excel and then take the next 200 values and put it into another excel
How can i do it using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library:

```
import pandas as pd    
dfs = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname=None)

#divide
df1=dfs[:200]
df2=dfs[200:400] and so on...

#saving divided dataframes to different excels
df1.to_excel("df1.xlsx")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but what if i don't know how many rows are there and i need to find the last row and then divide accordingly?

Comment: @GavyaMehta you can use `len(dfs)` or `len(df.index)` to count the rows

Answer (score 0):

1. pip install pandas.
2. Convert excel file to data-frame using pandas.
3. Then Slice the data-fame to 200 using simple python slicing method [:200]
4. now write the data-frame to new excel file
5. Again slice the old excel data-frame to ignore first 200 records.